# Prove that m=inf(A)

Tags: analysis

### Let be A a non-empty set of real numbers and m a real number.If (i) m$\leq$x for any x$\in$A and (ii) for any real number n>0, it exists an element x$\in$A such that x$\leq$m+n then prove that m=inf(A)

my idea was about choosing n=minimal and assuming that m < x for any x from A.Then x=m+r where r>0 so from (ii) it exists x$\in$A such that x$\leq$m+n or m+r$\leq$m+n so r$\leq$n and because n=minimal it results that r=n and then i choose n=the lowest number with the property that n(minimal)$\leq$n and do the same thing but i dont know if that thing is good in solving the problem.Another idea was Dirichlet's Theorem, to divide the interval [0,1] in p interals with the lenght 1/p for example if i choose n=1/2 and then n=1/4 then for me it results using inequalities that x> -1 and maybe another values but i haven't continued with that.

Comment: There is no such thng as minimal postitve real number.

Comment: thanks for telling that i wasnt sure if my choose was correct

Comment: @mathematiciangrade8 minimal positive numbers do exist in some esoteric number systems (the kinds of systems non-standard analysis deal with) but you lose a lot of the nice properties that make the reals what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof by contradiction:
Suppose to the contrary that m is not the infimum of A, in other words, m is not the greatest number which is less than or equal to x for all x in A. Then since by (i) m is less than or equal to all x in A, then there must be some greater number r which is also less or equal to than all x in A. But then we can take n to be (r-m)/2, so by (ii) there exists an x in A such that x is no more than m+n=m+(r-m)/2

Comment: perfect, thank you!